# How do I write a query that inserts values while AND gets values from another table?

Tags: postgresql, select, query, insert, syntax

I have a table (Tbl2) that needs to be populated with values from another table (Tbl1).

Tbl1 has columns: `id (uuid), name, address, gender`.

Tbl2 has columns: `id (uuid), org, name, address, gender, createdAt, updatedAt`.

I want to copy `id, name, address, gender` from `tbl1` into `tbl2`. How Do I write a query that inserts those values into Tbl2 while also providing new ids, org, createdAt, and updatedAt values?

Comment: How would `org` be derived?

Comment: You say you want both copy "id", and generate it.  You can't do both.  Do you need two different id columns in tbl2 (id and tbl1_id)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [`DEFAULT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html) clause. I think you want something like the following as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2
(
  id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT)),
  org TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT SUBSTRING(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT) FROM 1 FOR 4),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  address TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  update_at  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  CONSTRAINT tbl2_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Note that I am using

```
  id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT))
```

as the `PRIMARY KEY`. This is close enough to a UUID for the purposes of this answer - I'm using dbfiddle (see this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0d69b44f4f9d64b16ac2b2ea5d2a341)) and can't install the `UUID` extension. I'm also using a `SUBSTRING` of the same function to generate the `org` field values, since I don't know exactly what that is - I would have thought that a reference table to things like the UN, EU, NATO, ASEAN... &c. would be more appropriate for this, but then, only you know that - see @Philᵀᴹ 's com

Then populate it with some values:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (name, address, gender)
VALUES
('Name_23', 'Address_23', 'M'),
('Name_24', 'Address_24', 'F'),
('Name_25', 'Address_25', 'M');
```

Notice how I don't have to specify the `id` or the `org` fields since there's a `DEFAULT` in place. Now, we do the same for `tbl1`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
  id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT)),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  address TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tbl1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (name, address, gender)
VALUES
('Name1', 'Address_1', 'M'),
('Name2', 'Address_2', 'F'),
('Name3', 'Address_3', 'M');
```

And then the `INSERT` is performed:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (name, address, gender)
SELECT name, address, gender
FROM tbl1 
-- WHERE tbl.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl1) -- MD5 should ensure uniqueness
RETURNING name, address, gender;  -- this is optional - check it out.
```

And then we check our `tbl2`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2;
```

Result:

```
id  org name    address gender  created_at  update_at
1feaceed5c2d8e37f5565d222b5bd31c    28a1    Name_23 Address_23  M   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00
508c0eecc16e305687b355c684cd5d56    d057    Name_24 Address_24  F   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00
247d6d7bdcef078c4b4f7bef33e91d01    78a5    Name_25 Address_25  M   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.366588+00
07bcc6cf6a3a3b79fcc05bafe9ebc8c2    05f8    Name1   Address_1   M   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00
029ef1b1c21df2a0fe25da352114aa1f    48c2    Name2   Address_2   F   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00
f4f51eccf9d4bfa7e011bdc4b2c135b8    8723    Name3   Address_3   M   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00   2020-02-26 05:43:28.395899+00
```

A simple inspection shows that our `INSERT` has worked. Finally, notice that our `created_at` and `updated_at` fields have also been included - as the default is `NOW()`. In order for the `updated_at` field to be modified automatically, you'll need to use a `TRIGGER` - if you do a search, there are millions on the all-singing, all-dancing web. If this doesn't answer your question, let me know and I'll see what I can do. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score -2):

Create a table mapping `tbl1.id` to the new values, then just insert into tbl2 a SELECT that joins those tables. Here's an example:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eSRqTAdH9b2cwfuJfwrJ1B/0